# How to add data to each item in a PagedList

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-paging

Let's say I am using an API to get a list of cars. This list is implemented and is working fine using a [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) with a [PageKeyedDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PageKeyedDataSource.html). The cars are showing up and when I scroll down, new cars are loaded and appended to the UI. Nice!

Now I want to show additional data for each car. Let's say the price for the car. This additional data is coming from another API endpoint. So as far as I understand, I have to find a way to use `DataSource.map()` or `DataSource.mapByPage()` to call the API for each car to receive its price. This price must then somehow be added to the list item.

I am using all the good stuff from the architecture components (LiveData, Data-binding, MVVM, and so on). For now I don't have a database and I would like to keep it like that. Retrofit is doing all the caching for me.

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out that the only meaningful approach is to add the data from the second API call within the `DataSource`. The reason for that is that the PagedList is considered immutable by the paging library. So before we either call `LoadInitialCallback.onResult()` or `LoadCallback.onResult()` all data should be prepared and available.

My DataSource looks like this now:

```
override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Car>) {

    val request = dataService.getCars(1) // load page 1 of all cars

    val response = request.execute()
    val items = response.body()?.values ?: emptyList()

    // we got the initial batch of cars -> now check them for prices
    fetchPrices(items, callback, nextPageKey = 2)
}

override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Repository>) {

    val request = dataService.getCars(params.key)

    request.enqueue(object : Callback<Cars> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cars>, response: Response<Cars>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val items = response.body()?.values ?: emptyList()
                retry = null

                // we got a batch of cars -> now check them for prices
                fetchPrices(items, afterCallback = callback, nextPageKey = params.key + 1)

            } 
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Repositories>, t: Throwable) {
            ...
        }
    })
}

/**
 * This method is checking all of the given [cars] for having a price.
 * If a car has a price, this is added to the car.
 * If all cars were checked, the onResult-callback of this DataSource is called
 * to signal the completion of getting the paged data.
 */
private fun fetchPrices(
    repositories: List<Car>,
    initialCallback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Car>? = null,
    afterCallback: LoadCallback<Int, Car>? = null,
    nextPageKey: Int
) {

    // used to count the server responses
    var checkedPrices = 0

    cars.forEach { car ->

        // enqueue the price request for this car
        val priceRequest = dataService.getPrice(car.id, 1)
        priceRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<Prices> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Prices>, t: Throwable) {
                // ignore failed requests, but still check for completion
                // to increase the checkedPrices counter.
                checkForCompletion()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cars>, response: Response<Cars>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful || response.body() == null) return
                val prices = (response.body() as Prices).values
                if (!prices.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    car.price = prices.first()
                }
                checkForCompletion()
            }

            // check if we got server responses for all cars.
            // If yes, call either the initialCallback or the afterCallback
            private fun checkForCompletion() {
                checkedPrices++
                if (checkedPrices >= cars.size) {
                    initialCallback?.onResult(repositories, 0, nextPageKey)
                    afterCallback?.onResult(repositories, nextPageKey)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```